# Bootstrap 3 button horizontal alignment issues within a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to place 5 buttons in a row. if i use "col-lg-3" the layout is getting too big, if i try to use col-lg-2 my fifth button is wrapping up. How to avoid that ? What is the best way to deal with alignment issues in such cases where if you go a higher number you get more space and if you lower your number in col-lg-xx you get less space ?? Following is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<link href="Content/theme/bootstrap-theme-slate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    #calculator{
    border:2px solid red ;
    margin-top:5%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div id="calculator" class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3">
                 <div class="row">
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="result" value="" />
                 </div>
                 <div class="row">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">MC</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">MR</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">MS</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">M+</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">M-</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
    </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already added the `.row` class on your buttons container, use `.col-xx` classes on your buttons, to get a full controled button grid :

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="calculator" class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="result" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 btn btn-default">MC</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-lg-2 btn btn-default">MR</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-lg-2 btn btn-default">MS</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-lg-2 btn btn-default">M+</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-lg-2 btn btn-default">M-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution i was looking for. Thanks so much. It worked

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to set this answer as "accepted" (you can do the same for your other questions).

Comment: Sure. Just did that. Sorry since i am kind of new in posting my question to stackoverflow i am still trying get use to of this. Was trying vote up your answer but since i do not have enough reputations i can't do that :)